# Error Building Redox OS on PeppermintOS 10

Tags: linux, rust, redox-os

I am unable to build [Redox-OS](https://github.com/redox-os/redox), an open source OS written in Rust. When I run:

```
shoaib@peppermint ~Desktop/RyneOS/redox $ make all
```

It responds with a couple of errors:

```
rm -rf "prefix/x86_64-unknown-redox/relibc-install.partial" "prefix/x86_64-unknown-redox/relibc-install"
cp -r "prefix/x86_64-unknown-redox/rust-install" "prefix/x86_64-unknown-redox/relibc-install.partial"
rm -rf "prefix/x86_64-unknown-redox/relibc-install.partial/x86_64-unknown-redox/include/"*
cp -r "prefix/x86_64-unknown-redox/rust-install/x86_64-unknown-redox/include/c++" "prefix/x86_64-unknown-redox/relibc-install.partial/x86_64-unknown-redox/include/c++"
cd "/home/shoaib/Desktop/RyneOS/redox/relibc" && \
export PATH="/home/shoaib/Desktop/RyneOS/redox/prefix/x86_64-unknown-redox/relibc-install.partial/bin:$PATH" && \
export CARGO="env -u CARGO xargo" && \
make -j `nproc` all && \
make -j `nproc` install DESTDIR="/home/shoaib/Desktop/RyneOS/redox/prefix/x86_64-unknown-redox/relibc-install.partial/x86_64-unknown-redox"
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/shoaib/Desktop/RyneOS/redox/relibc'
CARGO_INCREMENTAL=0 env -u CARGO xargo rustc --release  "--target=x86_64-unknown-redox" -- --emit link="target/x86_64-unknown-redox"/release/librelibc.a 
rm -rf "target/x86_64-unknown-redox"/pthreads-emb "target/x86_64-unknown-redox"/pthreads-emb.partial
mkdir -p "target/x86_64-unknown-redox"
cp -r pthreads-emb "target/x86_64-unknown-redox"/pthreads-emb.partial
thread 'main' panicked at 'unexpected -vV format', /home/shoaib/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rustc_version-0.1.7/src/lib.rs:126:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Makefile:173: recipe for target '"target/x86_64-unknown-redox"/release/librelibc.a' failed
make[1]: *** ["target/x86_64-unknown-redox"/release/librelibc.a] Error 101
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
mv "target/x86_64-unknown-redox"/pthreads-emb.partial "target/x86_64-unknown-redox"/pthreads-emb
touch "target/x86_64-unknown-redox"/pthreads-emb
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/shoaib/Desktop/RyneOS/redox/relibc'
mk/prefix.mk:19: recipe for target 'prefix/x86_64-unknown-redox/relibc-install' failed
make: *** [prefix/x86_64-unknown-redox/relibc-install] Error 2
```

My host OS: Peppermint 10

The OS I am going to build is Redox-OS with the name of RyneOS

I have all packages, rustc, rustup, etc. installed, I am on a 64 bit machine, I have also tried running `make qemu` but same problem.

Comment: has anyone solved this?